# NO DNS on Windows Virtual Server 2005 R2. Host: Windows7 Guest: Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, virtualization

The title is pretty self-explanatory.

I'm using Windows Virtual Server 2005 R2. The host OS is Windows 7. The guest OS in Virtual Server is Windows Server 2003. It seems like somehow, DNS doesn't work correctly on the guest OS. I am able to ping and even navigate to websites fine using their IP, but I can't browse them by using their URL. Here's what the ping returns:

> Ping request could not find host
>   www.google.com. Please check the name
>   and try again.

Also, I can ping the host from the guest just fine.

What am I missing? Any ideas what I should check?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas what I should check?

How about checking to make sure that your DNS servers are either set correctly in your Network Properties (in the case of static configuration), or are being sent/received correctly from your DHCP server.

Comment: I think they're being sent/received correctly from the DHCP. The're the same on both the guest and the host.

Comment: Have you confirmed this? `ipconfig --all` will tell you for sure if your DNS servers are being set properly.

Comment: Yes, I ran ipconfig /all on both guest and host and the DNS servers are the same on both (as is the default gateway and DHCP server)

Answer (score 0):

A few things you could check

- Are your nameservers reachable via IP?
- Can you query the nameservers directly (Start > run > cmd > nslookup > "server " > "google.be")
- If you traceroute your nameservers, do they pass some stranges hops?